# Codeigniter Pagination links not working. Showing 404 page

Tags: codeigniter, pagination, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

**My model code**

```
public function show_active_cat($limit,$offset) {
            $query = $this->db->select()
                    ->from('categories')
                    ->where('status', 1)
                     ->limit($limit, $offset)
                    ->order_by('created', 'DESC')
                    ->get();         

            return $query->result();

      }

        public function num_rows() {            
            $query = $this->db
                    ->select('id,cat_name,parrent_id,status')
                    ->from('categories')
                    ->where('status',1)
                    ->get();
            return $query->num_rows();
      }
```

**Controller Code**

```
 public function categories($page = 'categories') {
        if (!file_exists('application/views/public/' . $page . '.php')) {
              show_404();
        } else {
              $this->load->library('pagination');    
           $config = [
                  'base_url' => base_url('pages/categories'),
                  'per_page' => 2,
                  'total_rows' => $this->categorymodel->num_rows(),
                  'uri_segment' => 3,
                  'full_tag_open' => "<ul class='pagination'>",
                  'full_tag_close' => "</ul>",
                  'first_tag_open' => '<li>',
                  'first_tag_close' => '</li>',
                  'last_tag_open' => '<li>',
                  'last_tag_close' => '</li>',
                  'next_tag_open' => '<li>',
                  'next_tag_close' => '</li>',
                  'prev_tag_open' => '<li>',
                  'prev_tag_close' => '</li>',
                  'num_tag_open' => '<li>',
                  'num_tag_close' => '</li>',
                  'cur_tag_open' => "<li class='active'><a>",
                  'cur_tag_close' => '</a></li>',
              ];
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['cat_list'] = $this->categorymodel->show_active_cat($config['per_page'], $this->uri->segment(3));
        $this->load->view('templates/public-header');
        $this->load->view('public/categories',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/public-footer');
        }
  }
```

**My htaccess**

```
  <IfModule authz_core_module>
    RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
 </IfModule>
```

Deny from all

The problem is when I try to click a panination link to get the next records then url is:  http://192.168.1.66:2020/ci/pages/categories/2
Message:
404 Page Not Found

The page you requested was not found.

Comment: Try `'uri_segment' => 4,`

Comment: Rejoanul Alam I have already tried 'uri_segment' => 4, but it's not working

Comment: Have you tried `site_url('pages/categories')` ??

Comment: Yes i am already tried site_url() but still facing same problem

Comment: Rejoanul Alam  Please see my paging html url                                                                                                <ul class="pagination"><li class="active"><a>1</a></li><li><a href="http://192.168.1.66:2020/ci/index.php/pages/categories/2" data-ci-pagination-page="2">2</a></li><a href="http://192.168.1.66:2020/ci/index.php/pages/categories/2" data-ci-pagination-page="2" rel="next">&gt;</a></li></ul>                                           This is my paging html  url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i found solution when i removed if statement and then its worked fine

```
    `if (!file_exists('application/views/public/' . $page . '.php')) 
     {
        show_404();
     }`
```